# Loop though each observation in SAS

Tags: loops, sas

Let say I have a table of 10000 observations:

```
Obs X Y Z
1
2
3
...
10000
```

For each observation, I create a macro: mymacro(X, Y, Z) where I use X, Y, Z like inputs. My macro create a table with 1 observation, 4 new variables var1, var2, var3, var4.

I would like to know how to loop through 10000 observations in my initial set, and the result would be like:

```
Obs X Y Z Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1
2
3
...
10000
```

Update:

The calculation of Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4:

I have a reference table:

```
Z    25          26          27          28          29          30   
0    10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000   
1    10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000   
2    10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000   
3    10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000      10 000   
4    9 269       9 322       9 322       9 381       9 381       9 436   
5    8 508       8 619       8 619       8 743       8 743       8 850   
6    7 731       7 914       7 914       8 102       8 102       8 258   
7    6 805       7 040       7 040       7 280       7 280       7 484   
8    5 864       6 137       6 137       6 421       6 421       6 655   
9    5 025       5 328       5 328       5 629       5 629       5 929   
10   4 359       4 648       4 648       4 934       4 934       5 320
```

And my have set is like:

```
Obs X   Y   Z
1   27  4   9
2           
3           
            
            
10000
```

So for the first observation (27, 4, 9):

Var1 = (8 619+ 7 914+  7 040 + 6 137 + 5 328)/  9 322

Var2 = (8 743+  8 102+  7 280+ 6 421  + 5 629 )/ 9 381

So that:

Var1 = Sum of all number in column 27 (X), from the observation 5 (Z+1)  to the observation 9 (Z), and divided by the value in the (column 27 (X) - observation 4 (Z))

Var2 = Sum of all number in column 28 (X+1), from the observation 5 (Z+1)  to the observation 9 (Z), and divided by the value in the (column 28 (X+1) - observation 4 (Z))

Comment: Show the computation of `var1-var4`.  You may need only a DATA step, in which case the question is from extreme new SAS coder.  A more complicated computation may need multiple steps, or DOSUBL side session execution.  https://communities.sas.com is a good resource for questions when just learning to code SAS and you haven't tried anything.

Comment: Please look at my update. In fact I created a fucntion but it takes quite a long time (4 variables * 10000 times), so I would like to see if there is any faster way.

Comment: What are values like `8 619`? Is the space a decimal point so that the number is less than 9?  Or is the space just be removed so the number is larger than 8 thousand?

Comment: Ah sorry, it means 8 thousand.

Answer (score 3):

I would convert the reference table to a form that lets you do the calculations for all observations at once.  So make your reference table into a tall structure, either by transposing the existing table or just reading it that way to start with:

```
data ref_tall;
  input z @;
  do col=25 to 30 ;
    input value :comma9. @; 
    output;
  end;
datalines;
 0    10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000   
 1    10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000   
 2    10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000   
 3    10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000   
 4     9,269       9,322       9,322       9,381       9,381       9,436   
 5     8,508       8,619       8,619       8,743       8,743       8,850   
 6     7,731       7,914       7,914       8,102       8,102       8,258   
 7     6,805       7,040       7,040       7,280       7,280       7,484   
 8     5,864       6,137       6,137       6,421       6,421       6,655   
 9     5,025       5,328       5,328       5,629       5,629       5,929   
10     4,359       4,648       4,648       4,934       4,934       5,320   
;
```

Now take your list table HAVE:

```
data have;
  input id x y z;
  datalines;
1 27 4 9
2 25 2 4
;
```

And combine it with the reference table and make your calculations:

```
proc sql ;
create table want1 as
  select a.id
       , sum(b.value)/min(c.value) as var1
  from have a
  left join ref_tall b
    on a.x=b.col
    and b.z between a.y+1 and a.z
  left join ref_tall c
    on a.x=c.col
    and c.z = a.y
  group by a.id
;
create table want2 as
  select a.id
       , sum(d.value)/min(e.value) as var2
  from have a
  left join ref_tall d
    on a.x+1=d.col
    and d.z between a.y+1 and a.z
  left join ref_tall e
    on a.x+1=e.col
    and e.z = a.y
  group by a.id
;
create table want as
   select *
   from want1 natural join want2 natural join have
;
quit;
```

Results:

```
Obs    id     x    y    z      var1       var2

 1      1    27    4    9    3.75864    3.85620
 2      2    25    2    4    1.92690    1.93220
```

Comment: I tried your code but var1 in my defintion shoud be 3.75, not 18.79?

Comment: The extra joins for VAR2 calculations is confusing things.  Not sure yet if you can do it in one pass, for now just do VAR1 and VAR2 calculations in separate steps.

Comment: Ok it works if I do the calculations in seprate steps and the code runs quicky.

Comment: Note if you have multiple ID values that are using the same values for X,Y,Z then you can save time by selecting just doing the calculations for distinct X,Y,Z from your HAVE list and then remerge with HAVE based on X,Y,Z to get ID and VAR1 matched up again.

Comment: Updated code to reflect calculating VAR1 and VAR2 in separate queries.

Answer (score 2):

The reference table can be established in an `array` that makes performing the specified computations easy.  The reference values can than be accessed using a *direct address* reference.

Example

The reference table data was moved into a data set so the values can be changed over time or reloaded from some source such as Excel.  The reference values can be loaded into an array for use during a DATA step.

```
* reference information in data set, x property column names are _<num>;

data ref;
  input z (_25-_30) (comma9. &); 
  datalines;
0    10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000   
1    10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000   
2    10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000   
3    10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000      10,000   
4    9,269       9,322       9,322       9,381       9,381       9,436   
5    8,508       8,619       8,619       8,743       8,743       8,850   
6    7,731       7,914       7,914       8,102       8,102       8,258   
7    6,805       7,040       7,040       7,280       7,280       7,484   
8    5,864       6,137       6,137       6,421       6,421       6,655   
9    5,025       5,328       5,328       5,629       5,629       5,929   
10   4,359       4,648       4,648       4,934       4,934       5,320   
;

* computation parameters, might be a thousand of them specified;

data have;
  input id x y z;
  datalines;
1 27 4 9
;

* perform computation for each parameters specified;

data want;
  set have;

  array ref[0:10,1:30] _temporary_;

  if _n_ = 1 then do ref_row = 0 by 1 until (last_ref);
    * load reference data into an array for direct addressing during computation;
    set ref end=last_ref;
    array ref_cols _25-_30;

    do index = 1 to dim(ref_cols);
      colname = vname(ref_cols[index]);
      colnum  = input(substr(colname,2),8.);
      ref[ref_row,colnum] = ref_cols[index];
    end;
  end;

  * perform computation for parameters specified;

  array vars var1-var4;

  do index = 1 to dim(vars);
    ref_column = x + index - 1 ;   * column x, then x+1, then x+2, then x+3;

    numerator = 0;                 * algorithm against reference data;
    do ref_row = y+1 to z;
      numerator + ref[ref_row,ref_column];      
    end;

    denominator = ref[y,ref_column];

    vars[index] = numerator / denominator;  * result;
  end;

  keep id x y z numerator denominator var1-var4;
run;
```

Comment: What is "last_ref" in your code? And you can explain why you created the array ref[0:10,1:30]? Does it work if we use the array ref[0:10,25:30]? And I'm trying to figure out that in the set have, z=9 but in the set want, z = 10?

Comment: And if I add one more line in the have set, I dont get the correct output? You can check it again?